# Issue with LinkedStack pushing a cloned object in java

Tags: java

when I ran this code tmp is not null and can be printed model's info

but when I push it into linkedStack, it tells me NullpointerException

```js
    
    private LinkedStack<GameModel> modelStack;
    
    protected GameModel clone()  {
        try{
            GameModel tmp;
            tmp= (GameModel)super.clone();
            // tmp.dotSet=dotSet;
            // tmp.numberOfSteps=numberOfSteps;
            //tmp.numberOfSteps=numberOfSteps.clone();
            System.out.println(tmp);
            return tmp;
        }catch (CloneNotSupportedException e){
            throw new AssertionError();
        }      
    }
    
    private void createModelStack(GameModel model){
        GameModel tmp;
        tmp=model.clone();
        System.out.println(tmp);
        System.out.println(tmp==null);
        modelStack.push(tmp);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private LinkedStack<GameModel> modelStack
```

modelStack is not initialized. This is what's null, not tmp.

Just make sure you instantiate it:

```
private LinkedStack<GameModel> modelStack = new LinkedStack<>();
```

Or if you want you can create it in `createModelStack` instead, which probably makes even more sense

The other thing, is that I'm not familiar with `LinkedStack`, and it doesn't appear to be a java implementation. Did you implement it yourself? An error could be being thrown from there as well (if in your actual code you instantiated the modelStack and forgot to include it here)

Comment: @赖智伟 You should accept an answer if it answered your question!